# How do I print this 2 D array next to the appropriate row?

Tags: java

```
    //Game Summary
    System.out.println("Game Summary");
    System.out.println("------------");

    System.out.print(teams[0] + ":");

    for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < scores[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.printf("%3d", scores[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();;
        System.out.print(teams[1] +":");

    }
```

I have a program that asks the user for the scores for each team in a football game and records them in a double array, scores[][], and another array that stores the team names, teams[]. There is another method below that adds the scores up. When I run the program it prints the team[1] twice. How do I fix this? Example is below

```
Game Summary
------------
Ravens: 14 21  3  7

Steelers:  0  0  0  0

Steelers:Ravens:45 //(here is the problem, team[1] is printed twice)

Steelers:0
```

Comment: `System.out.print(teams[1] +":");` this is in your for loop

Comment: @Compass Where would I place this line?

Comment: You are printing `teams[1]` each time. You probably wanted `teams[i]` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your case. As I understand, you want to avoid duplication of teams.
You can try to use this solution:

```
    int[][] scores = {{14, 21, 3, 7}, {0,0,0,0}};
    String teams[] = {"Ravens", "Steelers"};
    System.out.println("Game Summary");
    System.out.println("------------");

    for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(teams[i] +":");
        for (int j = 0; j < scores[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.printf("%3d", scores[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Outputs:

```
Game Summary
------------
Ravens: 14 21  3  7
Steelers:  0  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write a little class like this...

```
private static class FootballTeam
{
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Integer> scoreList;

    public FootballTeam(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.scoreList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public FootballTeam(String name, int ... scores)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.scoreList = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int score : scores)
        {
            this.scoreList.add(score);
        }
    }

    // getter and setter methods ...

    @Override public String toString()
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        builder.append(this.name);

        for(int score : this.scoreList)
        {
            builder.append(String.format("%3i", score));
        }

        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this...

```
FootballTeam [] teams = new FootballTeam [NumberOfTeams];

// read in scores and store it in the football team objects with the setter methods

System.out.println("Game Summary");
System.out.println("------------");

for(FootballTeam team : teams)
{
    System.out.println(team.toString());
}
```